# How to create a query to join three tables and make calculations in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm just at the beginning of my SQL studies and can't figure out how to resolve the next problem.

So, there are three tables:

! [given tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZH1s.png)

The task is: "Get number of pet type per owner"
Write a query to generate the result below:

! [desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy5BJ.png)

The best result I have for the moment:

```
SELECT owners.OWNER_NAME, COUNT(pets.OWNER_ID) AS pets 
FROM owners
JOIN pets ON owners.ID = pets.OWNER_ID
JOIN pet_type ON pets.TYPE = pet_type.ID 
GROUP BY owners.OWNER_NAME;
```

It returns first column with owner names and second column with the sum of particular owner pets.

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Please review [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as many old timers will downvote questions like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  o.OWNER_NAME, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN t.name = 'CAT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CAT, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN t.name = 'DOG' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DOG,
  SUM(CASE WHEN t.name = 'SNAKE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) SNAKE
FROM owners o
JOIN pets p ON o.ID = p.OWNER_ID
JOIN pet_type t ON p.TYPE = t.ID 
GROUP BY o.OWNER_NAME;
```

I use `name` as the name of the column describing the type in table `pet_type`. Change it to the actual name of the column.

Answer (score 0):

Check this. To Get number of pet type per owner, this is sufficient to join only Pets table with the owners table. A DISTINCT count of Pet.Type will give your desired output.

```
SELECT
owners.ID,
owners.OWNER_NAME, 
COUNT(DISTINCT pets.TYPE) AS Num_Pet_Type 
FROM owners
INNER JOIN pets ON owners.ID = pets.OWNER_ID
GROUP BY owners.ID,owners.OWNER_NAME;
```

If you wants number of Pet per type, use this below script-

```
SELECT
owners.ID,
owners.OWNER_NAME, 
pets.TYPE,
COUNT(*) AS Num_Of_Pet
FROM owners
INNER JOIN pets ON owners.ID = pets.OWNER_ID
GROUP BY owners.ID,owners.OWNER_NAME,pets.TYPE;
```

Comment: Thanks! But it returns something like that:
----------------------------------------
owner_name    num_pet_type
----------------------------------------
MARIE             1
SUE                 1
TOM                1

Comment: Not clear what is returning. The script should return something like - ID:101, OWNER_Name: XYZ, Num_Pet_Type: N

Comment: The result indicates MARIE has 1 type of Pet. May be there are more than 1 Pet but all of them are belongs to single type like may be 'Dog'

Comment: Yeah, I have understood what you were trying to say. We counted pet types, that's why input shows that every owner has only one pet type.

Comment: Yes, you got my point. I have also added the query for getting total number of pets per type. You can also check that query.